# How to make LIKE in SQLite to check for first few characters only

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause, sql-like

I have a table with a column "Sentence"

```
Sentence
---------------------------
I eat chocolate today
I go to Hospital I am Hurt
I went to sleep Bye
I am very Hungry
I am done
You are beautiful
```

I am using the query

```
SELECT * from table WHERE Sentence LIKE '%am%'
```

This will return

```
I go to Hospital I am Hurt
I am very Hungry
I am done
```

But I want the LIKE Statement to return

```
I am very Hungry
I am done
```

only.

So Is there any way so I can make LIKE statement to check for the first 8 characters or something like that?
Help me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substr()` to get the first eight characters and apply the `LIKE` operation on them.

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat
       WHERE substr(sentence, 1, 8) LIKE '%am%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE Sentence LIKE 'I am %'
```

This matches on values that start with `'I am '` - which would produce the expected results for your sample data.